# ActiveRecord not saving any attributes, saving default values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `User` model with some attributes, call them `foo` and `bar`.  So my model looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :foo, :bar
end
```

Then I do the following:

```
user = User.new
user.foo = "123"
user.save!
```

And my development log shows:

```
INSERT INTO "users" DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING "id"
```

Then if I go into the Rails console and do `User.first` I get something like:

```
#<User id: 4, foo: nil, bar: nil>
```

I am using Postgres and I am having no trouble saving other models to the database, why is my `User` model saving default values?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`attr_accessor` is overriding the rails attributes. Try removing it and it should work.

Comment: This must be postrges-specific.  Does anyone know why?

Comment: I'd love to know why Postgres is the issue.