# Writes to database empty records when I check validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with validates:

```
attr_accessor :name, :username, :email, :password

validates :name, :presence => { allow_blank: false, message: "Имя не может быть пустым" }
validates :username, :presence => { allow_blank: false, message: "Имя пользователя не может быть пустым" }
validates :email, :presence => { allow_blank: false, message: "Эл. адрес не может быть пустым" }
```

CREATE def:

```
def create
@user= User.new(user_params)
if @user.save
redirect_to "http://bookworm.az:3000"
else
        session[:name] =@user.name
        session[:username] =@user.username
        session[:email] =@user.email

        error =@user.errors.to_a.to_sentence(two_words_connector:',')
        delimeter = error.split
        error = error.gsub(delimeter[0], '')

        show_error = error.split(",")

        flash[:notice] = show_error[0]
        redirect_to :back
end
end
```

When I delete ALL validates checking all it saves the user in the database. But with the validates LOG prints:

```
INSERT INTO "users" DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING "id"
```

What is the problem?

**UPDATE**

```
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :username, :email, :password)
end
```

Comment: Can you type `user_params` method ?

Comment: Sure! I add the user_params method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`attr_accessor` is overriding the rails attributes. Try removing it and it should work.

Read the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17540828/2791480) for similar issue.